# Edit to add substantial context or new answer

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer

So [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71592548/4700841), actually solves my problem.

However, to make it a truly useful answer, it needs significant amounts of context and explanation adding as well as actual code.

I feel like I should edit it to add this. However, by the time I've done so, there will likely be more content that I've written than in the original answer. Given it did solve my problem and I want the user to receive credit for this, what should I do?

Comment: There are plenty of meta questions about this. What is the canonical?

Comment: Why did you ask this question if you did not worry about the answer you were given?

Answer (score 29):

The answer seems self-sufficient. If you can provide a better explanation then you should post an answer of your own. You can upvote the other answer that helped you arrive at your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Gonna be a contrarian for a moment.

There's nothing wrong with editing an answer (citing the "why edit a post" section of the help page for editing) to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it (excepting the correction of "minor" mistakes).

You might want to note that the only guideline for avoiding an edit on the basis of size alone is that if the edit is not substantial enough. So if your edit is substantial, you then have two important questions to ask about your edit:

1. Will your edit of the post not *meaningfully* change what it means?  This should be a "No".
2. Will your edit *meaningfully* clarify what it means?  This should be a "Yes".

**If you sincerely have no doubts about those, go for it.** Exactly what constitutes meaningful change is to some extent going to be a matter of opinion. If you don't think you could justify these answers to someone, then don't edit. Leave a comment or add an additional answer & cite the original answer if appropriate.

In this specific case, adding examples of how to deal with non public methods does not change the original meaning of the post and does clarify it. I would argue your edit abides by the guidelines currently set out.

I will say that you would have also been justified in adding your own answer if you were to have chosen that course of action instead.

Comment: I would advise caution in considering whether adding examples does not go against the initial intent. Many answers are intentionally on point; bloating therm with examples can make them worse as it detracts from the key message.